# Is it possible for an Android alarm clock app to not turn on the screen when it rings?

Tags: battery-life, screen, alarm

Recently, I asked [this question requesting recommendations for an Android alarm clock that does not turn on the screen when it rings](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78117/reliable-android-alarm-clock-that-does-not-turn-on-the-screen-when-the-alarm-rin) on Software Recommendations StackExchange.

The reason I do not want the screen to come on while the alarm is ringing is because I want to reduce battery drain while the alarm is ringing.

I have yet to receive any responses, and I'm still searching for such an app.  That got me wondering: Is it even possible for an Android alarm clock app to ***not*** turn on the screen when it rings?

Comment: Definitely possible the app decides if just a tune is played or other actions are taken. My favorite [Teatimer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andreasmiklautsch.teatime) works this way. You may need to change some config settings.

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert.  I'm looking at Teatimer now to see if it can also work as an alarm clock.  How can one tell if it is actually leaving the screen off vs. displaying all black pixels?

Comment: @Robert I might have figured out a method to determine if the screen is just filled with black pixels or is actually in standby (which I'm not sure if that's the same as screen off... do you know?).  Many Android devices have an LED that will illuminate when the device is charging and is in standby.  From what I can tell, that LED is not illuminated when the device is charging and not in standby.  So that LED may be a good indicator.  I'm not sure if this technique works in all cases though.

Comment: @Robert I tested the Teatimer app you recommended, and the LED I mentioned stays illuminated when the timer sounds, so if my test is accurate, then it looks like the screen is truly off.  (Curious if you know of another test.)

Comment: Are you talking about the notification LED? That LED is just an LED without any connection to the screen. It can be addressed by any app if I remember correctly via the notification system. In any way you can also disable blinking in timer settings.

Comment: @Robert Yes, the notification LED.  In this case, I'm just using it as a possible technique to see if the screen is really off or just filled with black pixels.  Do you know of a better way?

Comment: As I said the LED has nothing to do with the screen. And why would someone show a black screen? I am not sure if this is possible at all if the device is locked. I would check logcat for screen events.

Comment: @Robert To answer your question, see https://github.com/JonasBernard/FakeStandby